# Mach-O file LC_FUNCTION_STARTS load command

Tags: macos, mach-o, dyld

Does anyone know what the format of the data pointed to by the Mach-O LC_FUNCTION_STARTS command is?

The most information I could find is in the loader.h header file:

```
#define LC_FUNCTION_STARTS 0x26 /* compressed table of function start addresses */
```

I see the dyldinfo tool has a -function_starts option which analyzes this data and the tool is open source, but the latest released version of the tool doesn't contain the support:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-97.2/src/other/dyldinfo.cpp

Does anyone know where I can get the source for the latest version of dyldinfo, or where I can get more information on this load command?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I found the link to a newer version of dyldinfo: http://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-127.2/src/other/dyldinfo.cpp. I always seem to find answers to my own questions as soon as I post them here (:

Comment: A more important question - does the loader actually use this command and if so why? Doesn't it have sufficient information as to where the start() location is based on the exports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't got any additional answers or comments in a few days I thought I might as well answer this myself. The solution is basically what I put in a comment above:

The newest version of dyldinfo is located here:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-127.2/src/other/dyldinfo.cpp

However I still never figured out exactly what the function starts are used for, if anyone has info on that I'd still appreciate it.

Answer (score 14):

It's used by tools that need to symbolicate addresses in crash logs, samples, spindumps, etc. to determine if a given address falls inside a function. It could also be useful to debuggers to help them more quickly find the bounds of the function that a given address is within.

The data within this section is formatted as a zero-terminated sequence of [DWARF-style ULEB128](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128) values. The first value is the offset from the start of the __TEXT segment to the start of the first function. The remaining values is the offset to the start of the next function.

Comment: It's mostly useful for tools that need to operate on a stripped executable.  For instance, a debugger that wants to do a stack walk needs to know where all the functions start in `__TEXT` so it can look at the prologue instructions and see how the stack was modified and where registers were saved.  But in a stripped executable, the symbols for most of the functions are missing.  The LC_FUNCTION_STARTS gives the debugger that information.